# matplotlib drawing the wrong graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I have been trying to use `matplotlib` in Python to automatically draw the results of a modelling program I am using, which gives out a test file with columns, each representing different results, but when I go into Python to draw it, the only result is a very wrong graph, as I have previously drawn said graph in excel.

Here is a snippet of the file results (it is much longer than this):

```
0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
  3.000000E-04  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
  6.000000E-04  2.887798E-08  1.680484E-14
  9.000000E-04  6.581382E-07  5.739958E-13
  1.200000E-03  7.335421E-06  9.660436E-12
  1.500000E-03  5.342088E-05  1.069121E-10
  1.800000E-03  2.866680E-04  8.761781E-10
  2.100000E-03  1.212496E-03  5.678235E-09
  2.400000E-03  4.224012E-03  3.035017E-08
  2.700000E-03  1.251032E-02  1.378038E-07
  3.000000E-03  3.227664E-02  5.433805E-07
  3.300000E-03  7.397857E-02  1.893237E-06
  3.600000E-03  1.531101E-01  5.911080E-06
  3.900000E-03  2.901264E-01  1.673348E-05
  4.200000E-03  5.093375E-01  4.338243E-05
  4.500000E-03  8.369451E-01  1.039025E-04
  4.800000E-03  1.298646E+00  2.316557E-04
  5.100000E-03  1.917294E+00  4.840755E-04
```

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.loadtxt("mikro.out", usecols=0, dtype='str')
c240 = np.loadtxt("mikro.out", usecols=1, dtype='str')
c489 = np.loadtxt("mikro.out", usecols=2, dtype='str')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(t, c240, color='r', label='modelled 240 cm')
ax.plot(t, c489, color='g', label='modelled 489 cm')
ax.ticklabel_format(axis="both", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
ax.set_xlabel("time [s]")
ax.set_ylabel("concentration [ug/L]")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And here is the image it spits out:

[image: figure]

I have tried to change parameters and such, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I really cannot see the issue here. I am fairly new to Python and very new to this library, so thanks for the help already!

Comment: `dtype='str'` why are you converting all the values to string?

Comment: The only error you have is `dtype='str'` when reading data from a file. Remove this part and enjoy the result (dtype will be set to `float` by default, which is appropriate for your case).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your code where you are loading in from the .out file. You are converting everything to a string with `dtype='str'` so it is plotting all those values as a string. Either remove `dtype='str'`, change it to `dtype='float'`, or convert all of your values into float before you plot them like:

```py
values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
values = [float(x) for x in values]

### Output
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```